# How can I ensure that switch label is aligned veritical with the actual control

Tags: material-ui

I have a component that opens/closes a material-ui table. I use a switch to open/close that component. This largely works exactly as I want. I have a minor aesthetic issue with the placement of the Hide/Show text. The top of the text aligns with the horizontal center of the switch control.

Here is the switch code.

```
<FormControlLabel
    className={classes.switch}
    control={<Switch checked={show} onChange={handleChangeShow} />}
    label={show ? "Hide" : "Show"}
  />
```

Notice that the Show/Hide label is not aligned with the switch itself. It's too low. How can I fix this?

[image]

Here is the makeStyles function.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
    flexDirection: "column",
    display: 'flex'
  },
  container: {
    width: (props) => (props.show ? "inherit" : "0px"),
    height: (props) => (props.show ? "inherit" : "0px")
  },
  switch: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "flex-end"
  },
}
```

Here is the wrapper code:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography>{title}</Typography>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Fade in={show}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>{frames_view}</Paper>
        </Fade>
      </div>
      <FormControlLabel
        className={classes.switch}
        control={<Switch checked={show} onChange={handleChangeShow} />}
        label={show ? "Hide" : "Show"}
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Looks like it was solved by wrapping in a FormGroup:

```
  <FormGroup
    className={classes.switch}
    row
  >
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<Switch checked={show} onChange={handleChangeShow} />}
      label={show ? "Hide" : "Show"}
    />
  </FormGroup>
```